# How are the eyelids controlled in autorig pro?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, auto-rig-pro

Let's just think about the upper right eyelid for the moment.  Autorig pro created the following controls:  c_eyelid_top.r, c_eyelid_top.01.r, c_eyelid_top.02.r, c_eyelid_top.03.r.  There are corresponding vertex groups for c_eyelid_top.01.r, c_eyelid_top.02.r, c_eyelid_top.03.r.

But there is no vertex group for c_eyelid_top.r.   The controller does move the eyelid, but the weights need adjustment.  But I can't find the vertex group to adjust the weights.  How can I adjust the weights for this controller?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the Autorig Pro rig. But have you checked the bones for the *Deform* option? Maybe *c_eyelid_top.r* is the main controller that only controls other bones? Only bones that have the *Bone Properties > Deform* option enabled deform the mesh and have a vertex group.

Comment: That seems to be the situation.  c_eyelid_top.r is a parent of c_eyelid_top.01.r and the others.  Thanks!